# How to build react native android app for production?

Tags: react-native

I've seen new release of react native for android and tried some examples. It works only with USB debug mode and "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081". How can I build android app for "production" including all dependencies and without react web-server connections.
Thank you.

Comment: did the solutions work for you? That process produces an unsigned apk for me, any pointers?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To build a release version of your Android app:

```
$ cd your-app-folder
$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

You'll need to set up signing keys for the Play Store, full documentation here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

Comment: Thank you. Waiting for better tools to do it. Correct me if I am wrong, for build release .apk there is no tools yet ?

Comment: from root-app directory try this `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` .   As per new documentations, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: @Martin thanks for that, but I seem to still have  trouble with that, that process generates an unsigned apk for me, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to sign it leveraging your keystore. Look over this - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Comment: @martin-konicek, this solution only generated an `app-release-unsigned.apk` which i tried installing but didn't install. Anything in particular known to cause this? Thanks

Comment: @martin-konicek I have the same problem as you.

Comment: It better as well: `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ...`. After generate `app-release.apk`, you can run the release as well: `react-native run-android --variant release` in your root-app directory

Answer (score 28):

You will have to create a key to sign the apk. Use below to create your key:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-app-key.keystore -alias my-app-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Use a password when prompted

Once the key is generated, use it to generate the installable build:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js \
  --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
  --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Generate the build using gradle

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Upload the APK to your phone. The -r flag will replace the existing app (if it exists)

```
adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/app-release-unsigned.apk
```

A more detailed description is mentioned here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: folder structure is updated, use `adb install -r ./app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk` to install on phone

Answer (score 17):

As for me, I add in my package.json to "scripts":

```
"release": "cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease"
```

And then in terminal I use:

```
npm run release
```

Or with yarn:

```
yarn release
```

Answer (score 5):

I have put together some steps that worked for me. Hopefully it would save time.

For bundling the package to work in local you need to do

```
$ curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

Then for compiling apk

```
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

I have added detailed instructions at : https://github.com/shyjal/reactnative-android-production

Answer (score 0):

To create a bundle of your android application to release application on play store.

```
cd /android
sudo ./gradlew bundleRelease
```

go to the `android/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.apk`

Upload this bundle on play store console.