# how to generate apk after finishing project on react native using Windows

Tags: android, react-native

My question is simple, I've finished writing the code for my android app with react native using Windows, now i need to create the apk. How do i do that?

Comment: If you use android studio, choose ``Build-> Generate Signed APK`` or if use eclipse, you can choose ``File->Export apk...``

Comment: thanks but i'm looking for a solution specific to react native.

Comment: You mean this? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content

Comment: Martin Konicek had answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/32631830/3765109

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cd path-to-folder 

cd android && gradlew.bat assembleRelease
```

This works perfectly, just make sure you have keystore setup in your gradle