# Error with react-native run-android --configuration Release

Tags: react-native

I run the following:

> $ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
>   $ react-native run-android
>   --configuration Release

And I get the following in response:

> Release JS server already running.
>
> Running adb -s HT68X0201778 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
>
> Generating the bundle for the
>   release build... Unable to parse cache file. Will clear and continue.
>   [01/07/2017, 19:52:45]  Initializing Packager [01/07/2017,
>   19:52:45]  Building Haste Map [01/07/2017, 19:52:47] 
>   Building Haste Map (2085ms) [01/07/2017, 19:52:47] 
>   Initializing Packager (2360ms) [01/07/2017, 19:52:47] 
>   Transforming files [01/07/2017, 19:52:48]    Transforming files
>   (1530ms)
>
> bundle: start bundle:
>
> finish bundle: Writing bundle output
>
> to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
>
> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle'

I tried running it as sudo as well, with no luck.

UPDATE: I manually created the 'assets' folder inside of 'android/app/src/main/' and ran it again. This time it got further, but still failed with the following:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * What went wrong: Task 'installRelease' not found in root project 'AppVendor'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallRelease'.

Comment: In the /android directory run the command `./gradlew tasks`. This should give you a list of all tasks available it might be that the installRelease tasks not exists or somehow the react-native cli command is running the glradle command from the wrong directory. you can run the same command directly with gradlew though.

Comment: Have you setup the [gradle signing config](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config)?

Comment: @tijs, thanks for the insight...

Comment: @max23_ I think the link you provided me was the most helpful for my scenario. If you want to provide your response as an Answer, I will mark it as The Answer.

Comment: I have added as an answer, glad it helps.

Comment: You need to follow this steps first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631830/3332734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config), "installRelease" gradle task will only available after editing the app's gradle at `android/app/build.gradle` with the following:

Please take note on the **signingConfigs** and **buildTypes** configs.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had everything except for updating buildTypes... the documentation doesn't make that very clear since they also show other parts of the existing config. They should have highlighted the *additions* needed. Anyway, it's working now. Thanks again!