# Build .apk for react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I am quite new to the react-native world. And so far i have not picked up on how to create an apk (i assume ipa would be similar) yet. I know there are some documentation entries and a lot of other questions that seem to answer that, but none of them works for me.

So the basic use case i would be interested in is building an apk for the demo application. Following the getting started i would do

```
create-react-native-app MyProject
```

Now i am able to start the packager and server and use expo. Perfect. But i want to build the apk now. All answers i found are either done via some kind of `cd android && ./gradlew build`, but there is no android folder in the application (apparently because expo takes care of it for non ejected apps). The other way would maybe to use `expo`, but i am running into errors all the way long. And as in the getting started guide `expo` is not directly mentioned, rather the `npm` commands it might not be the way to go.

I know about https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/signed-apk-android.html which requires the android folder. Also the `curl` version mentioned i.e. here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2943 which does not to the trick as well as all the methods in [How to build react native android app for production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32629379/how-to-build-react-native-android-app-for-production).

Answer (score 5):

Because you use [CRNA](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app) to create your project so `android`/`ios` folder (which contain build tools) does not exist.

CRNA configures your project to use the code that supported by the [Expo](https://github.com/expo) client app. But Expo XDE **does not have ability to build production app directly** (at this moment). So there are 2 ways:

1. [Eject and install the native code dependencies](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) for your CRNA app and build normally with adb/Android Studio or XCode
2. use `exp` (of Expo) which [recommended](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app#how-do-i-get-my-app-into-the-play-storeapp-store) by CRNA developers.

For 2nd choice: Run `npm install -g exp` to get it, login using Expo account. Config `app.json` like this:

```
{
   "expo": {
    "name": "Your App Name",
    "icon": "./path/to/your/app-icon.png",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "your-app-slug",
    "sdkVersion": "17.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.yourcompany.yourappname"
    }
   }
 }
```

And start the build by `exp start`. Once the app has started, run `exp build:android` or `exp build:ios` to build production app at platform that you need.

See: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/building-standalone-apps.html

Comment: Okay thank you for that. I am not using Expo XDE anyway. I find it a little bit weird that if you follow getting started via CRNA you do everything via `npm` and then you have to do building via `exp` which is mentioned nowhere in the react-native docs in my opinion. Also it gives a warning about not using the expo version of react. Next would be that expo building publishes these builds via URL and so imho following the getting started guide leaves you with no option to build locally (besides detaching)... should at least be mentioned. But thank you anyway. Guess there is no other way?

Comment: @patman `exp` which belong to Expo is recommended by CRNA developers. I've edited the answer, please have a look.